# Does a creature with Ability Focus produce poison crafting materials with a higher DC than normal?

Tags: dnd-3.5e, feats, crafting, poison

If you have ready access to the main ingredients of a poison (such as a trained creature that knows the "bestow poison" trick), you only have to pay 1/6 of the market price when crafting it instead of the normal 1/3. If the creature you are harvesting poison from has Ability Focus then the DC for their poison special ability is increased by two. Does this have any effect on crafted poison made using venom extracted from the creature?

I know that Wyvern poison is shown with a DC of 17 in the Arms and Equipment Guide. Also, in the SRD the Wyvern's poison ability has a DC of 17. In that same entry the Wyvern is shown to have the Ability Focus feat for its poison, which should increase the DC by two. Is this increase just not shown in its stat block, or does a Wyvern without Ability Focus actually have a DC 15 poison and because Wyverns normally have Ability Focus all of the poison available on the market is a better product because of that feat?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Feats with static bonuses are typically “baked in” to monster statblocks. Quite frankly, the statblocks wouldn’t be very useful if they weren’t—the whole point of them is to allow a DM to run the monster without having to calculate things, particularly for when they weren’t expecting a fight and don’t have time to plan something out.

The save DC against a creature’s natural poison is [usually calculated](https://www.d20srd.org/srd/specialAbilities.htm#poison) as 10 + ½ the creature’s HD + the creature’s Con modifier. In the specific case of the wyvern, that would be 10 + ½(7) + 2 = 15, but it has DC 17 because of Ability Focus.

As for the item “wyvern poison,” which has the same DC 17 save against the same effects as a wyvern’s natural poison, this is... kind of “coincidental” under the rules. The creature and the item are effectively independent rule elements that were just independently designed to line up, in order to match the narrative that they’re related. But poison items don’t have any formulas or rules; they’re designed arbitrarily, with the author just trying to find appropriate effects and DCs for the price.

So is the item’s DC 17 “because of” the creature’s Ability Focus feat? Under the rules, no; the item’s DC is just arbitrarily selected by the author. But, of course, the author chose DC 17 because that’s what the creature has, so in that sense, yes, the Ability Focus feat was incorporated in the item’s DC.

The key point here is that the author *could have* chosen a different DC if they wanted, for balance or any other reason. There’s nothing saying it’s “supposed to” match.

That said, *Drow of the Underdark* finally formalized a relationship between a creature’s natural poison, and poisons smeared on weapons:

> #### Handle Animal (Cha)

> In addition to the tricks described in the *Player’s Handbook* and elsewhere, drow commonly teach the following tricks to their vermin servants.

> **Bestow Venom (DC 15):** By succeeding on a DC 15 Handle Animal check to handle a vermin that has a poison special attack, you can compel the vermin to give up some of its venom. The creature deposits its poison into a container you indicate, providing a single dose. A Handle Animal check to extract venom takes 1 minute. You can then attempt a DC 15 Craft (poisonmaking) check to refine this venom into a poison you can use.

<sup>(*Drow of the Underdark*, pg. 46)</sup>

This is not super-well-defined, and it might be limited to just drow, and as written certainly is limited to only vermin, but most DMs (in my experience) allow it for any animal handler working with any kind of animal that has a natural poison. We also don’t know *precisely* what “refine this venom into a poison you can use” means—but the general consensus is that you get an item that, when smeared on a weapon, has the same effect as the creature’s natural venom, with the same DC. If this process is used on a wyvern, *then* the wyvern’s Ability Focus feat directly influences your poison item’s save DC.

But it’s equally plausible to say that “refine this venom into a poison you can use” just means you get the corresponding poison item, whatever it is. That is, if you had an *X* creature, and there was some “*X* poison” item, and their DCs didn’t match, this might arguably give you the statted item, even with the mismatch. Which could mean your custom-trained wyvern that doesn’t have Ability Focus might still offer DC 17 poison via this trick. Maybe.